# How to check whether user input matches with a word from a text file?

Tags: c#, arrays, dictionary, unity-game-engine, user-input

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class LetterRandomiser : MonoBehaviour
{
    public char[] characters; 

    public Text textbox; 

    public InputField mainInputField;

    void Start() /*when the game starts*/
    {
        char c = characters[Random.Range(0,characters.Length)];
        textbox.text = c.ToString(); 
    }

    void Update()
    {
        string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\lluc\Downloads\words_alpha.txt");

        foreach (string x in lines)
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Return) 
                && mainInputField.text.Contains(textbox.text) == true
                && mainInputField.text.Contains(x) == true)
            {
                char c = characters[Random.Range(0, characters.Length)];
                textbox.text = c.ToString();
                mainInputField.text = "";
            }
            else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Return) 
                && mainInputField.text.Contains(textbox.text) == false
                && mainInputField.text.Contains(x) == false)
            {
                mainInputField.text = "";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Reference to [my game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ev2W8.png)

No errors but when I run the game, it's very laggy. I presume it's because the program is reading the text file, words_alpha.txt, which contains all English words.

However even when it's laggy, when I enter a completely random word which does not match with any word from the text file, the program would still accept that word.

Something's wrong with my code...

What I want my code to do?

- Accept words which contain the randomly generated letters shown above the input box. (which works)
- Accept valid words that are in the English dictionary (in my case this is in the form of a text file called words_alpha.txt). (which doesn't work)

Comment: I could be wrong but it seems like maybe the lag could be happening because you are reading words_alpha.txt every frame in `Update()`. Maybe try reading the file once in `Start()` and then performing the check in `Update()`. So on `Update()` just loop through the file to check if the user inputted word is in the file.

Comment: Yes, the lag is better now. Thank you.

Comment: What about the loop? Still the same problem I assume?

Comment: This is just bad all round.   ```Update``` runs *every frame*, so at 60FPS it's running 60 times per second.  There is absolutely no way you should be iterating over each line every frame.  *At worst* you should check for ```GetKeyDown``` before running the for loop.  Ideally you'd put the for loop into a coroutine.

Comment: Yes I acknowledge that @Immersive that's why I was looking for an alternative solution to my problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read the file from the `Start()` method instead of the `Update()` because the file only needs to be read in once, rather than every frame. This will remove the lag.

Also you are looping through the file on every frame which is unnecessary. You should move

`if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Return))`

to outside the `foreach` loop. And you should probably have another function that is called inside that `if` statement. `Update()` should probably look something more like:

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Return) &&
        mainInputField.text.Contains(textbox.text))
    {
        wordIsInFile(mainInputField.text);
        //Remaining code that you want to use
    }

    else
    {
        //whatever needs to be done in the else statement
    }
}
```

Then the function that loops through the array:

```
void wordIsInFile(string word)
{
    foreach (var item in lines)
    {
        if (word == item)
        {
            //Perform tasks on word
            //and whatever else
        }
    }
}
```

Just declare `string[] lines` outside of `Start()`, but initialize it in `Start()`, to ensure that is a global variable. This will remove the lag, and be more efficient because you are not constantly looping through an array unless the `KeyCode` is pressed and `mainInputField` contains some string.

Comment: When I said the lag was better, it made a slight improvement. Now following this explanation, the code works as intended and there's NO lag what so ever. Thank you so much janzen!!!

Comment: Glad to help you!